# Delphi Error E1026 File not found: "myprojectname.tlb"

Tags: delphi, com, compiler-errors, typelib

I have a project let's call it Yellow.dproj, which I saved as Blue.dproj, to make some changes.  There must be some COM/DCOM related code in this project, but I can't figure out where.

The error I am getting when I try to build Yellow.dproj is that it can not find a type library (TLB) file:  "E1026 File not found: ".  The file it can't find is MyAppName.tlb.  There is a MyAppName_tlb.pas file, which I have tried adding and removing from the project, either way I get this error.

I think I probably have to go into that TLB file, which I don't really understand, and rename a bunch of junk in there, because it is dependant on the name of my application.  This is something that happens to you, I suspect, when you use COM/DCOM and type libraries in Delphi (Delphi 2010). You can't just rename or save-as and build a new project again.

What do I do to fix this unit up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have {$ *.TLB} in your project source?

The * is the project name, so the TLB file has to match the name of the project - perhaps the name of the tbl was not changed along with the project.

Comment: Turns out it did, and removing that fixed it.